# Trying to get pending transactions on ether. It shows error. Why?

Tags: python, transactions, filtering, web3py

Can anybody say why it shows error?

```
from web3 import Web3
infura_url = "wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/68d0375e0fb123458cbb6e028a24a82a"
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(infura_url))

block_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
```

Error:

> ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_newPendingTransactionFilter does not exist/is not available'}

I read the docs, google it, but can`t find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Infura does not provide that functionality.
Use Quicknode (trial and then you have to pay) or boot up your own eth node. I recommend you start with a test node, a lot faster to sync and you can test stuff while the mainnet is syncing